# Rundeck returning 409 on job run through REST API

Tags: rundeck

I am triggering job executions through the HTTP API using pyrundeck, which at the end just does an HTTP POST request like this:

```
POST https://rundeck.mycorp.com/api/18/job/1xf1c86f-az54-4830-b23f-acb435d60fa0/run
```

Some of the requests are returning 409 and I don't see references to any 409 response on rundeck documentation.

I have the feeling that might be a collision when the job is already running and a new request arrives but I still haven't confirmed that point.

Does a single node rundeck allows multiple executions of the same job in parallel?

Comment: Hi! Could you provide the full service.log output at the moment of receiving the 409 error? To allow multiple executions on a rundeck job just edit it, go to the "Other" tab, and set "Multiple Executions" to "Yes".

Comment: OMG ... wasnt aware about that switch!! ... is there any drawback on using that.
I have enabled ... lets see if 409 disapears

Comment: Added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow multiple executions on a rundeck job just edit it, go to the "Other" tab, and set "Multiple Executions" to "Yes".